# End of the year with Mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I'd like to have the week number and year, for a given date, from MySQL with the following rules:

- If the date is at the end of the year, but in the first week of the next year, I need to return 1 as the week number.
- If the date is at  the beginning of the year, but in the last week of the previous year, I need to return  52 (or 53) as the week number.

I've read the week function in MySQL but I can't get the result I want.

[Date and Time Functions: `WEEK(date[,mode])`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_week)

I am on the french calendar, so I have to begin the week on Monday and week 1 is the first week with more than 3 days this year.

Therefore I can only use options 1 and 3.

When I write the following queries:

- select week ('2012-12-31', 3), the result is 1
- select week ('2012-12-31', 1), the result is 53

When I test on the 1st Jan 2016:

- select week ('2016-1-1', 3), the result is 53
- select week ('2016-1-1', 1), the result is 0

Option 1 can't be used, because I can't detect that 2012-12-31 is in the next year.

Option 3 can be used, but I have the add two pieces of logic: if weeknumber = 1 and month = 12, year + 1 and if weekumber = 53 and month = 1 then year - 1

Does someone have a better solution?

Regards

Comment: I'm not exactly clear on your rules, but what about mode 7?

Comment: the mode 7 is "with a Monday in this year", so I can't use it ... it doesn't follow the french rules. on my need if the 1/1/2013 is week 1 and it is a thusday, I'd like to have the 12/31/2011 week 1 + year 2012. I think I have to use IF

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I think I get what you're trying to do now.

As the documentation says:

> We decided to return 0 instead because we want the function to return
>   “the week number in the given year.”

If you want the week number for the year that the week is in, they suggest using the [`YEARWEEK()` function](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_yearweek), which takes the same mode arguments as `WEEK()`:

> If you would prefer the result to be evaluated with respect to the
>   year that contains the first day of the week for the given date...
>   use the `YEARWEEK()` function:

```
 mysql> SELECT YEARWEEK('2000-01-01');
         -> 199952
 mysql> SELECT MID(YEARWEEK('2000-01-01'),5,2);
         -> '52'
```

So some examples of what you'd use:

```
mysql> SELECT MID(YEARWEEK('2012-1-1',3),5,2)
         -> '52'
mysql> SELECT MID(YEARWEEK('2012-12-31',3),5,2)
         -> '01'
```